# map() function throwing null error for response in Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement `Angular 2` code in `Angular 6` app and below is the code I am trying to implement.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-paging-in-kendo-grid-for-angular-2/

In the below code, I am getting error as null for json

```js
private getEmployee(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult>{  
    let params = new URLSearchParams();  
    params.set('Skip', state.skip);  
    params.set('Take', state.take)  
    return this.http  
        .get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params })  
        .map(response => response.json())  
        .map(response => (<GridDataResult>{  
            data: response.EmployeeList,  
            total: response.Count  
        }));  
      
}
```

The error is as below when I run the app

[image: Json Error]

Could you please tell me why it is throwing these 2 errors

Here is the subscription for the above code snippet.

```
public query(state): void {  
    this.getEmployee(state)  
        .subscribe(x =>super.next(x));  
}
```

In the `C#` code, I am return the `data` and `total` as below...

```
if (resultList.Count > 0)
{
    var result = new
    {
        data = resultList.ToArray(),
        total= resultList[0].TotalRecords
    };
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    return jsonData;
}
```

I get the below error when I implemented as you suggested @StepUp

[image: Array Buffer]

[image: DataGridResult]

[image: EmployeeList]

**EDIT**

It is not able to recognize the data we get from dataJson as mentioned in the Answer because it is a constant. Should we need to create a mapping class in Angular side?

Comment: TRy running in incognito mode and see if you are still getting the error?

Comment: When I run in incognito mode, the first error is gone. But still the second error is coming i.e., null.

Comment: Actually, the error says that 'response' is null, not 'json'.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Is it because, it is loading for the first time? How to put if condition in the middle of the map function?

Comment: where is the subscription to this function?

Comment: Edited the Question with Subscription.

Comment: you dont need `.map(response => response.json()) ` in Angular 6 bTW. it was needed in `2` . Did you debug if the `response`  in null

Comment: When I remove the mentioned statement, I am getting error in the next line. Not able to recognize `response.data` and `response.total`. Red swiggly for `data` and `total`. Also added the code on how I am returning the `data` and `total` in `C# WebApi`.

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting for the response before doing `map` ?

Comment: I don't know. I am not clear on how this `Angular` code works. You can see the complete code in `Angular 2` in the link provided in the question.

Comment: It would be good if anyone does the same sample in `Angular 6!!` with Server Side pagination :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more used to Promises so here is my way of implementation with Promises :

```
private async getEmployee(state: any): Promise<GridDataResult> {  
  let params = new URLSearchParams();  
  params.set('Skip', state.skip);  
  params.set('Take', state.take);
  const dataJson = await this.http.get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params }).toPromise();

  // Don't forget to check if dataJson is null, otherwise dataJson.EmployeeList will throw
  // EDIT
  const dataGridResult: GridDataResult = {
        data: dataJson.EmployeeList,  
        total: dataJson.Count  
  }

  return dataGridResult;
  
 }   

public async query(state): Promise<void> {  
    const dataGridResult:GridDataResult = await this.getEmployee(state);  
    super.next(dataGridResult);
}
```

**EDIT**

I added a type `<{ EmployeeList: any[], Count: any}>` with properties typed with `any`. Replace it by something more precise if possible.

```
const dataJson = <{ EmployeeList: any[], Count: any}> await this.http.get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params }).toPromise();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it.

Comment: Getting red swiggly error as `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.`  for first map method.

Comment: If I remove first `map` method, it is throwing error at second `map` method. So, I have used `pipe` for this. But when I use `pipe`, it finally throws red swiggly at `data` and `total`. Back to Square one :(

Comment: For `dataJson`, it is not able to identify either `pipe` or `map`.

Comment: In order to use `map`, dataJson needs to be an Array. Is it an array ? If yes, add `: type[]` after `const dataJson`, otherwise you don't need map and you can just create and return your `GridDataResult` in a variable.

Comment: The result we are getting is in the question. It returns `data` and `total`, the `C#` code.

Comment: If it returns an object with `data` and `total`, you don't map.

Comment: Could you please modify your Answer?

Comment: It's done. I have just one question, where do you find EmployeeList and Count ? Your `c#` return `data` and `total`, the `SerializeObject` transform into EmployeeList and Count ?

Comment: Instead of `EmployeeList` and `Count`, I have modified it into `data` and `total`. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241823/discussion-between-cpk-2011-and-archelite).

Comment: I am getting red swiggly at `EmployeeList` and `Count`. Question modified with latest screenshot of the error.

Comment: Still waiting for the response. The code is not able to recognize the `EmployeeList` and `Count`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call `.json` method. In addition, it is possible to use  `pipe` method to compose operators. The code can look like this:

```
return this.http  
    .get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params })      
        pipe(
            map(response => (<GridDataResult>{  
               data: response.EmployeeList,  
               total: response.Count  
            })), catchError( error => {
            return throwError( 'Something went wrong!' )
       });
    )
```

If you want to `map` items from array, then it is necessary to call `map` method of array:

```
mapToPerson(): Observable<Address[]> {
    this.getPersons
        .pipe(
            map((persons: Person[]) => persons.map(person => 
               person.address)))
        )
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It is necessary to understand why it throws error. So we an debug and find the problem. Let's try to simplify your code:

```
private getEmployee(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult>{  
    let params = new URLSearchParams();  
    params.set('Skip', state.skip);  
    params.set('Take', state.take)  
    return this.http  
        .get(this.BASE_URL, { search: params })  
}
```

and then see in console what you've got in `.subscribe` method:

```
public query(state): void {  
    this.getEmployee(state)  
        .subscribe(yourResponse => console.log(yourResponse ));  
}
```

After error will be figured out, you can add code from the reply.

Comment: Your code looks simple. But still it is throwing error at `EmployeeList` and `Count`.

Comment: What it would be for GridDataResult?

Comment: Could you please help me out on this? I am little bit not clear on this on how to proceed.

Comment: @CPK_2011 It is necessary to debug your code. Please, see my updated answer. And then apply `map` method if it is necessary

Comment: I have modified the question. With your code, it was throwing error for params and I have corrected it and then I got the error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @CPK it looks like you wrote `let params = new URLSearchParams();  and other code` in `http.get`. But it is necessary to put this code before `http.get`. Please, pay attention to the code example.

Comment: With your same code, it throws error as in the modified question.